# jQuery removeClass doesn't works the right way

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

There are two buttons (the black ones), and two (at the beginning small sized) green boxes with (red, but at beginning not showed) contents in them. My goal is to make working perfectly the following:

If I click on the first button, the first box gets a bigger size, and it's content is going to be visible. If the second box was big (and it's content visible), before the function of the first box begins, make disappear the second box's content, then make the box to the original size.
And so for clicking the second button, just make the second box bigger.

I tried to make it, and I don't see any logical mistake in the code. But if I click on the first button, it works still good, but after I click on the second button, everything goes wrong... The addClass() function adds the class "invisible" but after it removes immediately. And after the things just go from bad to worse...

Here is a demo of my page:
http://math.bme.hu/~mosonyip/Testing13/testing13.html

Please help me, I'm just a newbie in webprogramming, and also sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Please construct your codes in http://jsfiddle.net/ for it to be easily debugged.

Comment: Here is the site in jsfiddle, but I don't know how can I make my js work in it :(
http://jsfiddle.net/e98fgcg1/

Comment: To get your jsfiddle to work, you'll need to include jQuery (upper right). Here's a link with jQuery included: http://jsfiddle.net/e98fgcg1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I see is that you're re-binding your transtion events each time you click the button

```
$( "div.button-1" ).click( function() {
    if( $( "div.no2 div.inside" ).hasClass( "invisible" ) != true ) {

        // FOLLOWING LINE IS RE-BOUND EACH TIME WITH ON() 
        $( "div.no2 div.inside" ).addClass( "invisible" ).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function() {});
    });
})
```

This is the case in multiple places, so multiple event handlers are bound to your divs (no1, no2). Address this, and it'll probably fix your issues. (you can either call `off()` or bind the event handlers outside of your click handlers)

EDIT: Here's an updated fiddle that demonstrates calling `off` to prevent multiple-event binding (script cleaned up as well) : http://jsfiddle.net/e98fgcg1/2/

And the code changes:

```
var TRANSITIONS = 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd';

$('div.button-1, div.button-2').on('click', function() {
    var ORIGINAL = $(this).hasClass('button-1') ? 'div.no1' : 'div.no2';
    var SELECTOR = ORIGINAL === 'div.no1' ? 'div.no2' : 'div.no1';

    if ($(SELECTOR).find('div.inside').hasClass('invisible') !== true) {
        $(SELECTOR).find('div.inside').addClass('invisible').on(TRANSITIONS, function() {
            $(SELECTOR).find('div.inside').off(TRANSITIONS);
            $(SELECTOR).removeClass('bigger').on(TRANSITIONS, function() {
                $(SELECTOR).off(TRANSITIONS);
                $(SELECTOR).removeClass('z-index-2');
                $(ORIGINAL).addClass('z-index-2').addClass('bigger').on(TRANSITIONS, function() {
                    $(ORIGINAL).off(TRANSITIONS);
                    $(ORIGINAL).find('div.inside').removeClass('invisible');
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(ORIGINAL).addClass('z-index-2 bigger').on(TRANSITIONS, function() {
            $(ORIGINAL).off(TRANSITIONS);
            $(ORIGINAL).find('div.inside').removeClass('invisible');
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JackPattishall, as I see, I didn't know how "on" works... Your solution is perfect, thank you! :)